# Why won't HTML5 video controls show in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram API to pull posts to a website. If it's a video post I'm using (simplified)

```
<video id="id123" poster="img.jpg" controls>
 <source id="id123" src="instagramURL.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The controls show in Safari but NOT in Chrome. So the poster image shows but there's no way to play the video unless I put in `autoplay muted` which mutes the video and, without controls, there's no way to turn on the audio.

How do I get the controls to show?

Comment: I only have chromium on this computer but that works for me.

Comment: Show a link of demo page showing this problem in action...